# Airflow DAG Breaks with DefaultCredentialsError When Using Google OAuth2 id_token

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I'm trying to authenticate with Google Cloud Services using Apache Airflow . I've also ensured to paste the JSON key into the Airflow UI under the google_cloud_default connection.

```
def get_identity_token(service_url):
    # Create a hook specifying the 'conn_id' of the connection you've set up.
    hook = GoogleBaseHook(gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default')

    # Use the hook to get authentication info.
    creds = hook.get_credentials()

    # Use the auth info to get an identity token.
    auth_req = Request()
    token = id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, service_url)
    return token
```

However, every time I run my DAG, it breaks and I receive the following error:

`google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Neither metadata server or valid service account credentials are found.`